# Saving multiple images to a directory using python

Tags: python, opencv

Im trying to save multiple images  to a directory which is created by the user's input. Below is the code of how to create the directory:

```
while True:
        Name = input("Enter your name: ")
        try:
            os.mkdir(Name)
            break
        except FileExistsError:
            while True:
                remove =  str(input("Do you want to rewrite the directory?"))
                if remove=="yes" or remove=="Yes" or remove=="y" or remove=="Y":
                    shutil.rmtree(Name)
                    os.mkdir(Name)
                    break
                if remove=="no" or remove=="No" or remove=="n" or remove=="N":
                    pass
                else:
                    continue
            break
```

i know i did something wrong with the below code but i dont what is it since im only a beginner

```
if key == ord("k"):
        p = ("/dataset/Name/" + "{}.png".format(str(total).zfill(5)))
        cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
        total += 1


    elif key == ord("q"):
        break
```

it  is giving off this error

> cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
>   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /home/pi/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:661: >error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension >in function 'imwrite_'

tried john's suggestion of removing os.path.sep.join() from the p but it is saving to a non existent directory called Name. Name is supposed to be the variable for the users input. The images that were supposed to be saved where also nowhere to be found.

I dont know what happened but it is not working again. Below was the edited code

```
if key == ord("k"):
    p = (f"/dataset/{Name}/" + '.' + str(total) + ".png")
    cv2.imwrite(p, orig)
    total += 1
```

Comment: What is the value of `p` when this error happens?

Comment: im sorry im new, how do you look for its value? p is supposed to be the path  of the directory which the images should be saved.

Comment: Add the line `print(p)` before the `imwrite()` call, so you can see the value.

Comment: //d/a/t/a/s/e/t///N/a/m/e///0/0/0/0/0/./p/n/g

Comment: That's because you're using `os.path.sep.join()` incorrectly.  You don't need to use that function at all.  Just build the path as a plain string: `p = "/dataset/Name/{}.png".format(str(total).zfill(5))`

Comment: i  tried it, it  is trying to save to a directory called Name which is non existent it is simply a variable for  the users input.

Comment: Update the question with the new code.  Saying "I tried it" doesn't give us any details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should have replaced `"/dataset/Name/"` with `"/dataset/{Name}/"`, if you want to use the value of the user input, or use `.format()` to fill that if your python does not support f''-strings.

Comment: It works for both of your suggestion.  Thank you so much.